# Source not found debugging android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am debugging this function:

```
public int colorIntWithAlpha(int color){
  String colorStr;
  colorStr=Integer.toHexString(color);
  char[] strChar=colorStr.toCharArray();
  colorStr=String.valueOf(strChar,0,6);
  colorStr+="FF";
  return Integer.decode(colorStr);
}
```

And when it arrives at `colorStr=Integer.toHexString(color);` I get a message:

```
Class File Editor
Source not found
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attaching Java Source to Android projects in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182904/attaching-java-source-to-android-projects-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to show the source code of a Java JDK function, and Eclipse doesn't found it. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426084/how-do-i-view-jres-source-code-in-eclipse), and [this one](http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/) in case you want to step into the Android SDK functions while debugging (now you can download the Android sources using the Android SDK Manager.