# how to import Java-7 source code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-7

I have JDK7 and eclipse installed. I have written some POCs on Java7. I am trying to import source code of Java-7. But not find the right way.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean the Java 7 JDK source?

Comment: If you add a JDK and not a JRE, you should be able to see the sources. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426084/how-do-i-view-jres-source-code-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have to give `JDK 7` path. I had given `JRE-7` which is available with Eclipse. in class path and was checking.