# Where can I find the Java packages and the class?

Tags: java

I am learning Java and I have came across few packages like `util` package, `swing` package etc. I want to dig it more so my question is when we import any packages in our source code where can I see those packages and the class codes in my personal computer.

Let's say there is an `util` package and `ArrayList` class. So where can I find the `util` package and `ArrayList` class?

Can I make any changes to `ArrayList` class or any other class?

I am trying to have the packages and class code without Eclipse installation. I have installed JDK and JRE and running the Java files through command prompt and using Notepad++ for writing code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I view JRE's source code in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426084/how-do-i-view-jres-source-code-in-eclipse)

Comment: You can see the `ArrayList` class of course but you don't have to change the class usually. You can write your custom `ArrayList` class and then you can import from your own package. The `ArrayList` from `util` package should not be modified.

Comment: @shmosel I am trying to have the packages and class codes without Eclipse installation. I am running simple jdk and jre and the java files through command prompt and using notepad++ for writing codes

Comment: This is one of the reasons you want an ide like eclipse instead of a traditional editor. It helps you with all the things not in your own source code. I would suggest using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ in a browser as it is the web version of the public documentation for all standard Java classes

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I am beginner so i guess i should start with notepad++ . I think it gives the better understanding of how your code is executing

Comment: Yes. Then you need good documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`java.util.ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is provided by the JRE, it is in `rt.jar` (and you **can** *see* the [source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)).

*Can I make any changes to ArrayList class or any other class?*

You could sub-class `ArrayList` (or *simply* implement `List`), but you can't really **alter** built-in classes (and even if you could, your code would then not be portable).

Comment: when you say "your code would then not be portable" What do you mean by that ?

Comment: @luke Your `ArrayList` wouldn't exist on some other user's installation of Java (if you were to hack `rt.jar`), then your code might run on only one machine (instead of every installation of Java). Better to create your own sub-class and follow OOP.

Comment: When i checked for the packages in my laptop they are executable jar file. So how can i check the packages class codes in my laptop. Or it can not be seen ?

Comment: It's shipped in compiled byte-code form. You **can** download the source code for Java. I already gave you a link to the source.

Answer (score 1):

> where can I see those packages and the class codes in my personal computer.

Just click control key and right click of mouse at `ArrayList` Object if u use `eclipse` or `netbeans`

if not then  you find it here
 `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar`

> Can I make any changes to ArrayList class or any other class?

You can't simply.`java.util` package contains the collections framework, legacy collection classes, event model, date and time facilities, internationalization, and miscellaneous utility classes and is provided by `JRE`

Comment: I have mentioned I am not using eclipse or netbeans.